# how to display text field as phone number?

Tags: community

I have a text field, which displays a phone number. If phone number is up to 10 digit, I have to display the number (00)-0000-0000. If it's up to 11 digit, I have to display the number (00)-00000-0000.Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: is it a VF page?

Comment: It is not VF page. By using work flow.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this as an example for your query

Step1: To create the field with APIname `Phone_number_display__c` of text type;

Step2: Create the WorkFlow, click on New role button then select object that you want, provide role name TestPhone1 , set Evaluation criteria created and set the Rule Criteria

```
LEN( Phone_number_display__c ) >= 10
```

[image]
step3:- Add Action New field Update,then give the Name, then select the field to Update,then click on Next.

[image]
Step4:-select use a formula to set new value then click on show formula Editor,and set the formula
[image]
Step5:-click save

```
 LEN( Field_Name ) >= 10
```

To update the field use this code in formula section:-

```
IF(LEN(Field_Name) == 10, "(" & TRIM(LEFT(Field_Name, 2)) & ") - " & TRIM(LEFT(TRIM(RIGHT(Field_Name, 7)), 4)) & " - " & TRIM(RIGHT(TRIM(RIGHT(Field_Name, 7)), 4)), IF(LEN(Field_Name)==11, "(" & TRIM(LEFT(Field_Name, 4)) & ") - " & TRIM(LEFT(TRIM(RIGHT(Field_Name, 7)), 5) & " - " & TRIM(RIGHT(TRIM(RIGHT(Field_Name, 7)), 4))), Field_Name))
```

Comment: Ajay... please share your field update code so OP can use that code..

Comment: For rule criteria use this:-  LEN( Field_Name ) >= 10
 
 To update the field use this code in formula section:- 
 IF(LEN(Field_Name) == 10, "(" & TRIM(LEFT(Field_Name, 2)) & ") - " & TRIM(LEFT(TRIM(RIGHT(Field_Name, 7)), 4)) & " - " & TRIM(RIGHT(TRIM(RIGHT(Field_Name, 7)), 4)), IF(LEN(Field_Name)==11, "(" & TRIM(LEFT(Field_Name, 4)) & ") - " & TRIM(LEFT(TRIM(RIGHT(Field_Name, 7)), 5) & " - " & TRIM(RIGHT(TRIM(RIGHT(Field_Name, 7)), 4))), Field_Name))